# Chart.js adding tooltip with cashflow

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a chart.js graph of time of payment of each customer. In the tooltip of each bar, I want to include the cashflow percentage.

Right now i get all cashflow values on one bar, i want to assign one value to each bar:

[image graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOD6d.png)

I got these percentages saved in an array like:

```
var cashFlow = [86.84, -36.36];
```

code graph:

```
var timeOfPaymentChart = new Chart(timeOfPaymentChart, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: customers,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Days between invoice and payment ',
      data: paymentDays,
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'white',
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
      hoverBorderColor: 'white'
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        footer: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var cf = cashFlow;
          return "Cashflow: " + cf;
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    }
  }
});
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the tooltips.callbacks.footer function as follows and it will work as expected.

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    footer: tooltipItem => 'Cashflow: ' + cashFlow[tooltipItem[0].index]
  }
},
```

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works.

```js
var cashFlow = [86.84, -36.36];

var timeOfPaymentChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['MultiSafePay', 'Koll'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Days between invoice and payment ',
      data: [38, 22],
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'white',
      hoverBorderWidth: 3,
      hoverBorderColor: 'white'
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        footer: tooltipItem => 'Cashflow: ' + cashFlow[tooltipItem[0].index]
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```